# Can I Connect Visual Studio Code Directly to Server?

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using Visual Studio Community for years. When doing so I go to "File - Open Website". I enter an IP address, user name, and password. Then I work directly on off the server. Can I do the same in Visual Studio Code or is it necessary to download my website directory to my local machine, then use some sort of ftp extension to upload changes as I make them?

Comment: if you are using Azure, you can create an app, and debug it remotely

Comment: I never used or even know what Azure is. I have a server on Godaddy. I want to open Visual Studio Code, connect directly to my server without ever having to download any files to my computer. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Azure Cloud and debug deployed to [Azure Cloud](https://medium.com/@auchenberg/introducing-remote-debugging-of-node-js-apps-on-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-in-public-preview-9b8d83a6e1f0) applications: